# Json Parsing in Golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to parse a json from a third party software. It returns a json like this

```
{ 
   "top1/dir1": "10",
   "top1/dir2": "20",
   "top1/dir3": "30",
   "top2/diff_val1": "40"
}
```

JSONLint says this is a valid json. But I could not figure how I can parse this with golang.

The code I used to parse the json file above (to be clear I took the code from another stackoverflow post).

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
)

type mytype []map[string]string

func main() {
        var data mytype
        file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("t1.json")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(data)
}
```

When I do a go run main.go, I get the below error

$ go run main.go
2016/06/19 22:53:57 json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.mytype
exit status 1

I did try to parse this format with another library - "github.com/Jeffail/gabs", but was unsuccessful. Since this is a valid json, I am pretty sure this can be parsed, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Go package with methods for decoding JSON strings.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

Here is an example of usage:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
        {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
        {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
    ]`)
    type Animal struct {
        Name  string
        Order string
    }
    var animals []Animal
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &animals)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", animals)
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Malik, the type of the value whose pointer you pass is wrong. In this case, your type should be `map[string]interface{}` (preferably, because a JSON field might not store a string) or `map[string]string` instead of `[]map[string]string`. The brackets at the beginning are wrong: such would be an array of JSON objects.

Comment: I am familiar with json parsing in golang. This specific format is what I am not able to parse `{  "top1/dir1": "10, "top1/dir2": "20" }`

Comment: @SivaramKannan You should probably specify what you want the end result of the parsing to be to help us find an answer, right now your question is pretty vague, hence the downvotes.

Comment: Sorry about the vague question. I have updated my original post with the formatted json and the go code I am using to parse.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you have a small typo in your program. You've declared `mytype` as a slice of maps, rather than just a map.

Just change:

```
type mytype []map[string]string
```

To:

```
type mytype map[string]string
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/pZQl8jV5TC for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer provides a good example of decoding JSON, and links the relevant package. You don't provide much detail on what exactly is going wrong with your parsing, but if I had to take a guess I would say you're probably not creating an appropriate struct to contain the JSON once it is unmarshalled. Because Go is statically typed, it expects data to adhere to explicitly defined formats.

If you don't want to go to the trouble of defining structs, you could just use an empty interface object, which is sort of a catch all in Go. Simply declare a variable with the type []interface{}, and then pass it into the JSON unmarshal function. Hope this helps!